# Zend framework URL internationalization & routing

Tags: php, zend-framework

I would like to have internationalized urls for a better user experience (All in intranets, so no SEO to worry about).

So basically i would like URLS like this (in this example, english, dutch and french):

```
/en/products
/en/product/123/blue-box
/nl/producten
/nl/product/123/blauwe-doos
/fr/produits
/fr/produit/123/boite-bleue
```

The `/nl/` part is no problem at all and described all over SO and the internet. But my problem is with routing to the controllers and actions.

Currently i have extended from the default router and used Zend_Translate to translate everything to english and have controllers and actions based on the english names.

However i keep having the feeling that there should be a better way to do this. Does anyone know if there are standard components in zend framework for this or had perhaps already created something like this before.

specs:

```
PHP 5.4.4
Zend Framework 1.11.10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to copy your controllers.
I've done it this way:

```
$translate = new Zend_Translate(
  array(
    'adapter' => 'array',
    'content' => 'PATH_TO_LANGUAGES/en_url.php',
    'locale'  => 'en'
  )
);

$translate->addTranslation(array(
  'content' => 'PATH_TO_LANGUAGES/nl_url.php',
  'locale' => 'nl'
));

$translate->setLocale('en');

Zend_Controller_Router_Route::setDefaultTranslator($translate);
```

The language files look like this:
You can translate controllers or actions. But I don't know if you can translate query params, too.

```
// en_url.php
return array(
  'products' => 'products',
);

// nl_url.php
return array(
  'products' => 'producten',
);
```

Read more about it [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.routes.standard.translated-segments).

Comment: I could not find the existance of setDefaultTranslator. So i did the translation work myself by extending the router. This indeed makes it a lot cleaner. tnx!

Comment: @nvanesch I've inserted a link, so that you can read more about it.